# Generate GnuPG Pair In PHP

Tags: php, encryption, gnupg

Is there any way besides `exec()` to generate a keypair with GnuPG in PHP? From what I can tell, the PECL library doesn't have any functions to do this.

Comment: yes, there seems to be: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php

Comment: Right, there's a library for GnuPG, but there's no function to generate key pairs...

Answer (score 1):

Haven't found anything myself. `exec()` is the only possibility currently.

Answer (score -1):

I just found [this useful library](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) which should fit your needs!